# Trying to Make default from: "blah@gmail.com" dynamic in mailer ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

Here is my mailer

```
class ReferMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "sample@gmail.com"

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.refer_mailer.refer_email_confirmation.subject
  #
  def refer_email_confirmation(user)
    @user = user

    @greeting = "Hi"

    mail to: @user.email, subject: "Your Friend Referred You to Bangstyle"
  end
end
```

I am building a refer a friend emailing system. A current user can input their friend's first name, last name, and email in a form and this form will create a friend record that belongs to this user. After this friend gets saved in the db then the mailer above will get emailed out.

Everything is working perfectly.

for this line

```
default from: "sample@gmail.com"
```

Since the current user change, I want the line above to be the current user email instead and not be hard coded in.

How do you pass that variable into a mailer?

and here is my friends controller

```
class FriendsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = current_user
    @friend = Friend.new
  end 

  def create
    @friend = Friend.new(friend_params)
    @friend.user_id = current_user.id
      if @friend.save
        ReferMailer.refer_email_confirmation(@friend).deliver
        redirect_to new_user_friend_path 
        flash[:notice] = "Your friend will receive an email shortly"
      else 
        redirect_to new_user_friend_path
        flash[:notice] = "It didn't work you friend didn't receive the email"
      end
  end
end
```

also for this line

```
mail to: @user.email, subject: "Your Friend Referred You to Bangstyle"
```

I want "Your Friend" to be dynamic as well and be the `current_user.name` or something. I am new to using actionmailer. I read somewhere that I can pass in instance variables to the mailer (railscast) but not sure how to proceed ?

I have tried passing `current_user` into the mailer but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to remove the default e-mail.

1. Add `@user = current_user` to the create action
2. ...also change `ReferMailer.refer_email_confirmation(@friend).deliver` to `ReferMailer.refer_email_confirmation(@friend, @user).deliver`
3. In the mailer, change to:

```
    def refer_email_confirmation(friend, user)
      @friend = friend
      @user = user
      @greeting = "Hi"

      mail to: @friend.email, from: @user.email, subject: "#{@user.name} Referred You to Bangstyle"
    end
```

You are getting the error (1 for 2) because you are still only passing @friend (then renaming it to user, which is kind of a bad practice... I kept it consistent).  That should do it :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line `default from: "sample@gmail.com"` from the first line of `ReferMailer` class.

```
  def refer_email_confirmation(user,friend)  
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Registered", :from => friend.email)  
  end
```

And call this method
`ReferMailer.refer_email_confirmation(@user,@friend).deliver` in your FriendsController

Let me know it it helps

Comment: for this line `ReferMailer.refer_email_confirmation(@friend).deliver` I am getting `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)`. Also in your way does friend refer to my current user? I think user actually refers to the new Friend record. Should I pass in current_user through my controller mail class method calling?

Comment: as I said it should be `ReferMailer.refer_email_confirmation(@user,@friend).deliver` not what you typed in comment.